# Serialize ComponentModel.Container?

Tags: c#, serialization, containers, serializable, componentmodel

Is it possible to serialize (binary) a System.ComponentModel.Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not marked serializable.

Comment: I should have selected this a long time ago - it clearly answers my question. I didn't even answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

What is it you actually want to **do** here? As has been noted, you can't use `BinaryFormatter` unless the type is serializable, but you would also need to consider all the things that might be *contained* in the container. They would *also* need to be serializable.

You can get around the "must be `[Serializable]`" issue by not using `BinaryFormatter`, but most other serializers (for example `XmlSerializer`) would have a problem with not knowing all the subclasses up-front, and things like non-settable properties.

If you have the right .NET versions, you could also consider things like [`XamlWriter`](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL36/), which may provide some interesting possibilities.

Comment: What I'm doing has stemmed from several requirements. The application implements TcpChannels with a common data object. Since it is a MarshalByRefObject, it must be [Serializable]. I know that the CompnonentModel.Container can create a site for it's nested containers and components to communicate - I'm just not experienced with architecting that. I have a feeling that I soon will be. The components and containers are custom classes that will inherit IComponent.

Comment: @dboarman - I think you need to send a simple data model (DTO or similar) that *represents* the data you want to rehydrate; trying to send anything from ComponentModel isn't going to end well.

Comment: I've gathered that ComponentModel isn't going to really be the answer I'm looking for. I am creating custom 'components' that will be both container and components, building a tree-like structure. So, I will probably create the custom 'component' derived from the generic Node<T> - and a custom interface making the base component data type quite interchangeable.